# Clearing placeholder also clears variable value

Tags: powershell

### Issue

When assigning a (placeholder) hashtable to another variable and then resetting said hashtable, it also resets the value assigned to the variable.

### Questions

1. Why is it happening?
2. How can I prevent that?
3. Why does it only seem to be working this way for that specific example, but not if `$a` is a simple integer?

### MWE

```
$a = @{test=$true}
$b = $a
$b
$a.Clear()
$b
```

### Output

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
test                           True
```

The second call does not output anything as `$b` is now considered as empty.

Comment: it´s a special hashtable thing, not exactly sure why it happens but you can do this: `$b = $a.clone()`

Comment: Simple as that, thanks. I encourage you to write a proper answer so that I can accept it and close the thread. Though I would be happy if someone could explain why does that happen with hashtables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to do something like this:

```
$b = $a.Clone()
```

Otherwise, you are referencing the same thing with both $a and $b in regards to hashes.

Comment: It's because hashtables are objects and passed **_by reference_** versus **_by value_**.