# Powershell Clone Ordered Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Follow-up from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081883/clearing-placeholder-also-clears-variable-value).

### Issue

An ordered hashtable cannot be cloned.

### Question

Is there an "easy" way to do this? I have indeed found some examples that seem overly complicated for such a "simple" task.

### MWE

```
$a = [ordered]@{}
$b = $a.Clone()
```

### Output

`Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] does not contain a method named 'Clone'.`

Comment: Related: [Deep copy a dictionary (hashtable) in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7468707/11942268)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OrderedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) do not contain [Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.clone?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Hashtable_Clone) method (see also ICloneable interface). You have to do it manually:

```
$ordered = [ordered]@{a=1;b=2;c=3;d=4}
$ordered2 = [ordered]@{}
foreach ($pair in $ordered.GetEnumerator()) { $ordered2[$pair.Key] = $pair.Value }
```

Answer (score 4):

While the answer given by Paweł Dyl does clone the ordered hash, it is not a [Deep-Clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

In order to do that, you need to do this:

```
# create a deep-clone of an object
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($ms, $ordered)
$ms.Position = 0
$clone = $bf.Deserialize($ms)
$ms.Close()
```

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is obsoleted. Do you have a modern method?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to lose the ordered aspect of it, a quick solution could be to convert to a normal hashtable and use its Clone() method.

```bsh
$b=([hashtable]$a).Clone()
```